# Is it possible to plot an equation in LTspice? I am supposed to plot an equation like this v(t)=d/dt(ln(pout(t)) + kPout(t)

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice, laser, optoelectronics, plot

In the equation mentioned above, Pout is the voltage at some output node in my schematic. Is it possible to plot the above equation? how to plot v versus time?

Comment: No, that equation won't work due to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can plot many equations like that within the Waveform Viewer.  Either right-click anywhere in the plot window and click "Add Trace" (CTRL+A) or right-click the colored name for an existing trace to edit the expression.  The following is an example:

[image]

You must run a transient analysis to have the x-axis be time. Be careful when using the derivative function since it can produce super high spikes due to initial conditions and such.  You can change the x-axis to leave those sections out or adjust when your "time to start saving data" begins within the `.tran` statement (which is what I did).  See the built-in LTspice Help page titled [Waveform Arithmetic](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelpXVII/LTspiceHelp/html/Waveform_Arithmetic.htm) to see which functions are possible to use and for more information.